# Git Source Control shows files as changed even though contents are the same

Tags: git, github-for-windows

The Diff message in VS2012 Pending changes window is as below

`diff --git a/Common/JsonHelper.cs b/Common/JsonHelper.cs

index fbbf9de..451cd37 100644

--- a/Common/JsonHelper.cs

+++ b/Common/JsonHelper.cs`

What does the `a/  b/` mean? How could i fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: you probably have some trailing whitespace

Comment: [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)  I just find this perfect solution to EOL problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a/ refers to old file

b/ refers to new file

git's unified diff produces these prefixes.

About the changes: may be different EOL. Take care of autocrlf config.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

And how could I avoid that.
Because even I committed these files,they are still there.
I use Undo file Changes Or Discard Changes in GitHub for Windows,but it doesn't work.

Comment: Problem Solved by deleting the newline at the end of the file.

Finally I noticed that at the end of the Diff message is：
"\No newline at end of file"